# dictionary : search key strings with a like feature

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to search my keys in Dictionary with a like feature. I want to takes the keys begin with "a" or their 3rd letter is "e" or their 4rt letter is not "d"

in sql it is possible to write queries " where (key like '***a*') and (key not like 'd__**') " I want to have this feature for Dictionary . Any algorithm suggestion you have ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While this will be the SQL equivalent of a table scan, you can use LINQ or the `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods to search your dictionary for all values whose keys match a pattern:

Extension Method:

```
var values = dictionary.Where(pv => 
             pv.Key.StartsWith("A") || 
             (pv.Key.Length >= 3 && pv.Key[2] == 'e') || 
             pv.Key.Length < 4 || 
             pv.Key[3] != 'd').Select(pv => pv.Value);
```

LINQ:

```
var values = (from pv in dictionary
              where pv.Key.StartsWith("A") ||
                    (pv.Key.Legnth >= 3 && pv.Key[2] == 'e') ||
                    pv.Length < 4 ||
                    pv.Key[3] != 'd'
                    select pv.Value);
```

Note that the last part of both of these predicates pertains to your "fourth letter is not "d". I took that to mean that a string that was three characters (or fewer) long would match this. If you mean the string is at least four characters AND its fourth character is not "d", then the changes should be obvious.

Be aware that the primary (performance) benefit to the `Dictionary` class is using hash-based key lookups, which (in the average and best case) is O(1). Using a linear search like this is O(n), so something like this will, in general, be slower than an ordinary key lookup.

Answer (score 14):

You can access the Keys property of the Dictionary and then use a Linq query to evaluate your keys:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();

dictionary.Keys.Where( key => key.Contains("a")).ToList();
```

Comment: I vote this, but I think it is important to rember we actually perform a linear scan to apply the condiction.

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ

Something like this

```
myDic.Where(d=>d.Key.StartWith("a")).ToDictionary(d=>d.Key,d=>d.Value)
```

Or

```
myDic.Where(d=>d.Key.Contains("b")).ToDictionary(d=>d.Key,d=>d.Value)
```

Or

```
myDic.Where(d=>some other condition with d.Key).ToDictionary(d=>d.Key,d=>d.Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use Linq:

```
var query = myDict.Where(x => x.Key.IndexOf('a') > -1 && x.Key.IndexOf("d_") == -1);
```

Comment: `Select(x => x)` does nothing. While a `select` statement is required in an actual LINQ expression, it's not required in code that just uses the LINQ extension methods unless you're actually performing a transformation. In addition, this doesn't match his requested logic, but I've upvoted since it does point out the actual concept.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little extension I whipped up:

```
public static IList<string> KeysLikeAt(this Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, char letter, int index)
{
    return dictionary.Where(k => k.Key.Length > index && k.Key[index] == letter)
        .Select(k => k.Key).ToList();
}

public static IList<string> KeysNotLikeAt(this Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, char letter, int index)
{
    return dictionary.Where(k => k.Key.Length > index && k.Key[index] != letter)
        .Select(k => k.Key).ToList();
}
```

and you can use it like so:

```
IList<string> keysStartingWithA = dictionary.KeysLikeAt('a', 0);

IList<string> keysNotStartingWithD = dictionary.KeysNotLikeAt('d', 0);
```

Comment: Why would you actually do a search within the string using `IndexOf` rather than just using the indexer on the `string` class (while checking the length, of course)?